# function returning wrong index value

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello in my web page some portion of DOM element are generated dynamically
and I created a function in jquery to get the index value of the DOM element on mousedown event. But my function always returns 7.
this is my dom structure and function code:

```
<div id = "viewer">
<div id="pageContainer1" >
    <canvas id="page2" width="741" height="959"></canvas>
    <div class="textLayer">
        <div>......some text here....</div>
        <div>......some text here....</div>
        <div>......some text here....</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="pageContainer2" >
    <canvas id="page2" width="741" height="959"></canvas>
    <div class="textLayer">
        <div>......some text here....</div>
        <div>......some text here....</div>
        <div>......some text here....</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="pageContainer3" >
    <canvas id="page3" width="741" height="959"></canvas>
    <div class="textLayer">
        <div>......some text here....</div>
        <div>......some text here....</div>
        <div>......some text here....</div>
    </div>
</div>​
</div>

<script>
    var indexInital, pageStr, containerStr, selector;
    //function for highlighting
    $(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        pageStr = String(PDFView.page);
        containerStr = "\"#pageContainer".concat(pageStr);
        selector = containerStr.concat(" > .textLayer > div\"");    
        });
});

    $(function() {
    $('#viewer').on('mousedown', selector ,function () {   
       indexInitial = $(this).index();
       console.log(indexInitial);   });
});

</script>
```

In the above code only div with id viewer is static, the div inside it are dynamically generated

Comment: What are you expecting `selector` to be when `$('#viewer').on('mousedown', selector, ...` gets executed? And are you sure that `indexInitial` is coming out as `7` rather than `0`?

Comment: selector format is similar to this "#pageContainer[number of page] > .textlayer > div" and yes the outcome of indexInitial is 7

Comment: But `selector` is modified by the scroll handler and that probably won't be triggered until *after* `selector` is used in the `on` call. So, `selector` is `undefined` when it is used. Perhaps you should set up a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/, something doesn't add up here.

Comment: see the fiddle its returning 0 as indexInitial

Comment: And `selector` is `undefined` when it is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you really want to find the index of `this` with respect to the `<div>`s in its `.textLayer`. So given this:

```
<div class="textLayer">
    <div>......some text here....</div>
    <div>Pancakes</div>
    <div>......some text here....</div>
</div>
```

if you click on `<div>Pancakes</div>` you'd want to get one. If that's right, then you want to bind your handler like this:

```
$('#viewer').on('mousedown', '.textLayer div', function() { /* ... */ });
```

and you can throw away your `selector` variable completely. Then, inside the handler, you could do this:

```
$(this).siblings().add(this).index(this);
```

to get the local index of `this` or you could do this:

```
$(this).closest('.textLayer').find('div').index(this);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/U97DG/

The [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function looks sideways for elements at the same depth as `this`, then we put `this` into the set using [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/); that gives us `this` and its siblings in one set of elements so we can use [`index(this)`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to find out where `this` is in that set.

The other approach goes back up the DOM to the closest `<div class="textLayer">` using [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and then grabs all the `<div>`s inside it using [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/); for your HTML structure, that gives us the set of elements that `siblings` and `add` do so we can using `index(this)` again to find out where `this` is.

Either approach will continue to work as you add and remove `<div class="textLayer">` elements or the `<div>`s inside them.